# Set different variable name in each iteration

Tags: java

I am novice in programming. I have this code and I want to place a variable that stores a different `LatLng` for each iteration and I want to be able to use it outside the loop but I don´t know how do this. Can you help please? Thanks.

```
for(int i=0; i<mis_localizaciones.size();i++){
    LatLng name = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mis_localizaciones.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(mis_localizaciones.get(i).getLongitude()));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean you want a variable whose name is decided at runtime?

Comment: yes, LatLng name, name1, name2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't create a variable with a dynamic name.

You can, however, use a collection (specifically in this case, a `List`).

```
List<LatLng> names = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<mis_localizaciones.size();i++){
    names.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mis_localizaciones.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(mis_localizaciones.get(i).getLongitude())));
}

// now use names.get(0), names.get(1), names.get(2), etc...
```

Comment: it says The method add(Lat_Lng) in the type List<Lat_Lng> is not applicable for the arguments (LatLng)

Comment: @Elena is your class called `Lat_Lng` or `LatLng`?

Comment: My class is called Lat_Lng :)

Comment: @Elena then you want to create a `Lat_Lng`, not a `LatLng`, so use `new Lat_Lng` not `new LatLng`. By the way, having two classes with similar names is a bad idea for this exact reason. (Also, why did you use `LatLng` in your question then?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a collection (for instance, an `ArrayList`) stored in a variable, in which you can give a name (for example `names`). You simply initialize it and then use it:

```
//This is your list, stored in names variable.
List<LatLng> names = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

for(int i = 0; i<mis_localizaciones.size(); i++){
    //You can add elements to the list.
    names.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mis_localizaciones.get(i).getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(mis_localizaciones.get(i).getLongitude())));
}
```

Then you can index the elements, in a sense:

```
String name = names.get(0); // Returns the 1st element of the list.
System.out.println(name);   //Print it out.
```

Comment: it says The method add(Lat_Lng) in the type List<Lat_Lng> is not applicable for the arguments (LatLng)

Comment: You have put an underscore (_) in your type. If your class type is Lat_Lng, replace it in the list respectively.